# Java SocketException: Broken pipe with Mysql-connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

I am using **Spring-batch** to read **Mysql** data.

These following are my spring data configuration:

```
spring.datasource.batch.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.batch.url=jdbc:mysql://192.162.155.11:3306/my_db?autoReconnect=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
spring.datasource.batch.username=root
spring.datasource.batch.password=
spring.datasource.batch.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=60000
spring.datasource.batch.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.batch.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1 
spring.datasource.batch.tomcat.log-validation-errors=true
spring.datasource.batch.tomcat.initial-size=2
spring.datasource.batch.tomcat.max-active=2
spring.datasource.batch.tomcat.max-wait=60000

# Batch job details
spring.batch.chunk.size=1000
spring.batch.page.size=500000
spring.batch.allow.start.if.complete=true
spring.listener.message.ms=10
spring.batch.executor.pool=5
```

I run a scheduler after every 2 seconds which checks for any new `row` in MySQL and start the spring batch if any new data found in Mysql.

I am successfully able to read data from Mysql but the problem is that after some time I am getting this below **error**:

```
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1198)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1193)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:2903)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMetaData(ConnectionImpl.java:2898)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:331)
        ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 65,074,919 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 65,074,920 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3746)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2509)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2497)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2455)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1369)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3541)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3516)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1230)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:958)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:966)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3728)
```

Comment: This commonly occurs when there is a firewall between the app and the database.  The firewall doesn't like long running connections.  How long is the connection running before it gets cut?

Comment: Usually, I get this error after 8 or more hours after every time I restart my application. I am planning to put my application on production. But this error is roadblock on the same.

Comment: Do some network analysis.  My bet is that it's a firewall issue as mentioned in my previous comment.